# Start the process stopped with CreatEvent

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to get the processes information. My program uses createEvent to check if any process is stopped? If the process stops, the program will call and restart it.
    For project1 and project2 are any two projects. I wish when the program ran, if one of the two projects stopped, the program would call them back.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

HANDLE eventP1;
HANDLE eventP2;
HANDLE RunProcess(TCHAR* pszPath)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION procInf;
    STARTUPINFO startInf;
    memset(&procInf, 0, sizeof(procInf));
    memset(&startInf, 0, sizeof(startInf));

    BOOL result;
    result = CreateProcess(pszPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &startInf, &procInf);
    if (result == FALSE)
    {
    cout << "Process creation failed!" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
    else
    {
    CloseHandle(procInf.hThread);
    return procInf.hProcess;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
HANDLE hEndEvents[2];
    DWORD dwRet;
    eventP1 = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, _T("Global\\eventP1"));
    eventP2 = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, _T("Global\\eventP2"));


    hEndEvents[0] = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, _T("Global\\eventP1"));
    hEndEvents[1] = OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, _T("Global\\eventP2"));

    if (hEndEvents[0] == NULL || hEndEvents[1] == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Open Event " << endl;
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;

    }

    RunProcess(_T("D:\\Project_VuongDV\\VS2013\\DemoEventProcess\\Debug\\Project1.exe"));
    RunProcess(_T("D:\\Project_VuongDV\\VS2013\\DemoEventProcess\\Debug\\Project2.exe"));

    while (true)
    {
        dwRet = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hEndEvents, FALSE, INFINITE);
        if (dwRet == WAIT_OBJECT_0 || dwRet == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
        {
            Sleep(100);
            ResetEvent(hEndEvents[0]);
            ResetEvent(hEndEvents[1]);
            cout << "project1 and Project2 run" << endl;
            SetEvent(hEndEvents[0]);
            SetEvent(hEndEvents[1]);


        }

        else
        {
            cout << "WAIL FALSE" << endl;
            cout << "Thread error is" << GetLastError() << endl;
            RunProcess(_T("D:\\Project_VuongDV\\VS2013\\DemoEventProcess\\Debug\\Project1.exe"));
            RunProcess(_T("D:\\Project_VuongDV\\VS2013\\DemoEventProcess\\Debug\\Project2.exe"));

        }

    }

    CloseHandle(hEndEvents[1]);
    CloseHandle(hEndEvents[2]);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fail to see from this code what the purpose of these events is. You're supposed to wait on the process handles. Furthermore, the code reads as if you're a beginner, and then such inter-process communication is beyond your skill level. I think you're a beginner because you make the basic error of restarting both processes if something happens to only one of them.

Comment: Yes, I'm a beginner and I need help from you! Please help me.

Comment: TBH at this stage you probably should be doing textbook exercises. But for this program, the key insight should be that you shouldn't use events at all. You got fixated on the idea that you should use `CreateEvent`, but that is just your inexperience.

Comment: In your experience, what method should I use to do that?

Comment: As I said in my first comment, wait on the process handles. But since you are a beginner, don't run before you can walk. Start with one child process, not two.